# FreeRTOS built on windows xp to run on a Atmega32

Tags: microcontroller, avr, circuit, freertos

I downloaded FreeRTOS and I want to put it on a microcontroller 
([ATMega32](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/209)) on a PCB (I'll do it on a breadboard 1st) like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ppLCIAeeTs&list=UU29vXxkQfTCxH97fI0hD0Bg&index=9&feature=plcp). How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [site](http://www.freertos.org/porting-a-freertos-demo-to-different-hardware.html), build instructions are included with the source.

Did you look through that?

Comment: That wasn't the intent! Glad I had a useful answer for you.

Comment: Quick follow up. on the [supported devices page](http://www.freertos.org/a00090.html#ATMEL) Atmega32 is not on there. What should I do about that?

Comment: I'd imagine the toolchain setup would be similar to other Atmega products. It should get you some of the way there at least. I'm just guessing now, but there should be an applicable target with GCC available.

Comment: Here are some samples http://code.google.com/p/freertos-atmega32 and here are some notes on using avr-gcc with atmega32 http://paul.graysonfamily.org/thoughts/avrlinux/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10940/discussion-between-coder404-and-dwerner)

Answer (score 3):

There is an AVR323 demo, which is completely compatible with the AVR32 as it is the AVR32's predecessor.

http://www.freertos.org/a00098.html
http://www.freertos.org/AVR_IAR.html

Those are official ports, although rather old now.  There are also lots of contributed ports in the FreeRTOS Interactive! site.

http://interactive.freertos.org/forums/103473-atmel

Regards.